# No hashing on Password field in Laravel seeder

Tags: php, laravel

I've recently inherited a project from a Laravel developer to look at. Unfortunately, when I migrate and seed the user table, the password ciphering is not working, as follows:

```
public function run()
{
    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'email' => 'admin@site.co.uk',
        'first_name' => 'Site',
        'last_name' => 'Admin',
        'username' => 'admin',
        'password' => 'localhostPassword'
    ]);
}
```

When I run `php artisan migrate --seed` the password field is the string literal as above, and when I try to sign in it tells me that my password credentials are incorrect.

As I'm not an Artisan Laravel developer I'm not sure where to start, but I'm expecting the password field to be hashed like this `$2y$10$u/FcKFPKsgRs8whJZ6ODAO90qllmGjqROnkmuQnxcpynG6WaIbX8e`, which is what is generated when I use the register form in the current code base.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to hash it *before* storing it:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash; // <-- import it at the top

//

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'email' => 'admin@site.co.uk',
            'first_name' => 'Site',
            'last_name' => 'Admin',
            'username' => 'admin',
            'password' => Hash::make('localhostPassword') // <---- check this
        ]);
    }
```

Note: An alternative is to use the `bcrypt()` helper instead of the `Hash::make()` method.

Chech [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/hashing#basic-usage) regarding this aspect:

> ## Basic Usage
>
> You may hash a password by calling the `make` method on the `Hash`
> facade:
>
> ```php
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Http\Controllers;
>
> use Illuminate\Http\Request;
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
> use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
>
> class UpdatePasswordController extends Controller
> {
>     /**
>      * Update the password for the user.
>      *
>      * @param  Request  $request
>      * @return Response
>      */
>     public function update(Request $request)
>     {
>         // Validate the new password length...
>
>         $request->user()->fill([
>             'password' => Hash::make($request->newPassword)
>         ])->save();
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually `bcrypt` the password like below

```
public function run()
{
   DB::table('users')->insert([
      'email' => 'admin@site.co.uk',
      'first_name' => 'Site',
      'last_name' => 'Admin',
      'username' => 'admin',
      'password' => bcrypt('localhostPassword')
   ]);
}
```